# Unique dates from list

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, list

I'm trying to take values from the XML file and make a list of unique dates.
I got dates in XML file and there is more than one date in one day.

1. 01.01.2018.
2. 01.01.2018.
3. 01.02.2018.
4. 01.02.2018.
5. 01.03.2018.
6. 01.03.2018.
7. 01.04.2018.
8. 01.04.2018.

I want to take all of these dates and put them like this:

1. 01.01.2018.
2. 01.02.2018.
3. 01.03.2018.
4. 01.04.2018.

Basically, sort them in order and do not have more than one date that's same.

```
public static void ispisiAnalizuPoDanu()
    {
        List<Mjerenje> lMjerenja = UcitajMjerenja();
        /* kreirati listu jedinstvenih datuma */
        List<DateTime> jedinstveniDatumi = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime zadnji = new DateTime();
        foreach (Mjerenje mjerenje in lMjerenja)
        {
            if (zadnji != mjerenje.datum)
            {
                jedinstveniDatumi.Add(mjerenje.datum);
            }
            zadnji = mjerenje.datum;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();


        List<AnalizaPoDanu> analizePoDanima = new List<AnalizaPoDanu>();

        foreach (DateTime datum in jedinstveniDatumi)
        {
            /* RAČUNANJE UKUPNOG BROJA MJERENJA */
            int total = 0;
            int zbroj = 0;
            int mini = lMjerenja[0].vrijednost;
            int maks = lMjerenja[0].vrijednost;
            int prosjek = 0;
            foreach (var mjerenje in lMjerenja)
            {
                if (mjerenje.datum == datum)
                {
                    total = total + 1;
                    zbroj = zbroj + mjerenje.vrijednost;
                    if(mjerenje.vrijednost < mini)
                    {
                        mini = mjerenje.vrijednost;
                    }
                    if(mjerenje.vrijednost > maks)
                    {
                        maks = mjerenje.vrijednost;
                    }
                }
            }

            prosjek = zbroj / total;
            var analizaPoDanu = new AnalizaPoDanu(
                datum,
                total,
                mini,
                maks,
                prosjek
                );
            analizePoDanima.Add(analizaPoDanu);


        }
        /*RAČUNANJE STANDARDNE DEVIJACIJE*/

        Console.WriteLine("Prikaz svih mjerenja po danu: ");
        var table = new ConsoleTable("Datum", "Total: ", "Min", "Max", "Prosjek: ");
        foreach (AnalizaPoDanu mjerenje in analizePoDanima)
        {
            table.AddRow(mjerenje.Datum.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), mjerenje.Total, mjerenje.Min, mjerenje.Max, mjerenje.Prosjek);
        }
        table.Write();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Data sample:

```xml
<data>
<Mjerenja>
<Mjerenje id="1"  vrijednost="3" dan="1" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="2"  vrijednost="4" dan="1" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="3"  vrijednost="5" dan="3" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="4"  vrijednost="6" dan="4" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="5"  vrijednost="7" dan="5" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="6"  vrijednost="8" dan="6" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="7"  vrijednost="9" dan="7" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="8"  vrijednost="10" dan="2" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="9"  vrijednost="5" dan="2" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="10"  vrijednost="7" dan="4" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="11"  vrijednost="2" dan="6" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="12"  vrijednost="4" dan="5" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="13"  vrijednost="12" dan="5" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="14"  vrijednost="10" dan="3" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="15"  vrijednost="2" dan="7" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
<Mjerenje id="16"  vrijednost="3" dan="1" mjesec="1" godina="2018"></Mjerenje>
```

Comment: Real simply using XML Linq (newest version of xml parser in Net).   Need to see sample of xml file.

Comment: Sorry for posting a question this stupidly...

Comment: I added XML file to the question

Comment: You can check this sample https://dotnetfiddle.net/fi2row

Comment: Just a hint, for the next time you include a sample of dates.  You might want to explain that your dates are written Day, Month, Year, with dots as separator.  Everyone has a different date format.  You also might want to provide a translation to English of "vrijednost", "dan", "mjesec", and "godina".  The "godina" one is, I'm guessing "year"

Comment: But this just takes whats in the brackets I need dates and other values so I can calculate avarge min max etc...
This program will be used to write temperature values

Comment: Yes I apologise for that this is my first time on stack I just went heads in

Comment: It's croatian, Vrijednost = value, dan = day, mjesec = month, godina = year

Comment: Well firstly I will write my code in english this is a project for college.

Comment: THANKS TO EVERYONE problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication94
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Mjerenje").Select(x => new {
                id = (string)x.Attribute("id"),
                vrijednost = (int)x.Attribute("vrijednost"),
                date = new DateTime((int)x.Attribute("godina"), (int)x.Attribute("mjesec"), (int)x.Attribute("dan"))
            }).ToList();

            var groups = results.GroupBy(x => x.date).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the following classes (I'll be using English names, so everyone can read):

```
class Measurement // Mjerenje
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

class AnalysisPerDay // AnalizaPoDanu
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public double Min { get; set; }
    public double Max { get; set; }
    public double Average { get; set; }
}
```

and that you have already read and converted the XML file to a list:

```
List<Measurement> measurements = LoadMesaurements(); // UcitajMjerenja()
```

You can group by day and compute the statistics with LINQ:

```
List<AnalysisPerDay> analysis = measurements.
    GroupBy(m => m.Date)
    .Select(g => new AnalysisPerDay {
        Date = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
        Min = g.Min(m => m.Value),
        Max = g.Max(m => m.Value),
        Average = g.Average(m => m.Value),
    })
    .ToList();
```

To understand the query, note that `GroupBy` creates groups of type `IGrouping<DateTime, Measurement>` in a parameter `g`.

`g` has a `Key` property containing the date and is an `IEnumerable<Measurement>` containing all measurements of one day.